# VB.NET: Setting ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to set the following property but don't know where to put the code, I've tried putting it at the top of my main form but it just says 'Declaration Expected'

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False
```

I'm using VB.NET (Framework 4)

```
    Private Function sendAccReq(ByVal method As String)

    System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False

    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://api.betfair.com/exchange/account/json-rpc/v1/")
    Dim postData As String = "{""jsonrpc"": ""2.0"", ""method"": ""AccountAPING/v1.0/" & method & """}"
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)

    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ContentType = "application/json"
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
    request.Headers.Add("X-Application: " & appkey)
    request.Headers.Add("X-Authentication: " & sessionToken)

    Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    dataStream.Close()

    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()

    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

    reader.Close()
    dataStream.Close()
    response.Close()

    Return responseFromServer

End Function
```

It's still not working though, when I go into the properties of the request when debugging Expect100Continue is still showing as TRUE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem with the Betfair API, i added the line of code before i created every web request.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False 
Dim request = CreateWebRequest(New Uri(EndPoint))
```

It fixed the problem but im not 100% sure if it is the right place to put it.
Are you getting any errors after you have made a web request?

UPDATE:

There are some differences between my code and yours, below is how i'm creating the web request:

```
Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(New Uri(EndPoint))
request.Method = "POST"
request.ContentType = "application/json-rpc"
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptCharset, "ISO-8859-1,utf-8")
```

Have you looked at the code samples on GitHub, (i know they are C# but might help:)
https://github.com/betfair/API-NG-sample-code/blob/master/cSharp/Api-ng-sample-code/Api-ng-sample-code/JsonRpcClient.cs

Let me know how you get on,

Comment: Thanks Mike, yes I'm using Betfair as well, I've tried your solution but it's not changing the property to false for some reason (see edit to my original post).

Comment: Ok, I put the line in my Form_Load section and it's working now. Thanks.